# Strange visibility error in Code::Blocks with C++

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I do some academic project on C++, using Code::Blocks, and I get some strange visibility errors.

The partial main file is:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define DEFContainerSize 100
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

#include "iteration1.cpp"
#include "iteration2.cpp"

int main(int argNum, char *args[])
{
    //Content skipped here!!
}
```

Included iteration1.cpp contains definitions like this:

//partial iteration1.cpp

```
//Content skipped here!!

        template <class Coords, class Rad>
        struct
Circle  {
            Coords Coordinates;
            Rad    Radius;
        };

//Content skipped here!!

        template <class Coords, class Rad>
        istream
    &operator>>(istream &input, Circle<Coords,Rad> &circle)
        {
            StringFunctionAndArguments fa;
            input>>fa;
            proc_FromStringFunctionAndArguments2<Coords,Rad>
                (fa,"Circle","operator>>",circle.Coordinates,circle.Radius);
            return input;
        };

        template <class Coords, class Rad>
        ostream
    &operator<<(ostream &output, Circle<Coords,Rad> &circle)
        {
            output<<"Circle("<<circle.Coordinates<<","<<circle.Radius<<")";
            return output;
        };

//Content skipped here!!
```

And this works just fine. But when I try to put similar definition in iteration2.cpp:

```
//iteration2.cpp this time full file.

        template <class Coords>
        struct
Triangle
        {
            Coords Coordinates1,
                   Coordinates2,
                   Coordinates3;
        };

        template <class Coords>
        istream
    &operator>>(istream &input, Triangle<Coords> &tr)
        {
            StringFunctionAndArguments fa;
            input>>fa;
            proc_FromStringFunctionAndArguments2<Coords,Coords>
                (fa,"Triangle","operator>>",tr.Coordinates1,
                                            tr.Coordinates2);
            tr.Coordinates3 = fa.Arguments.back();
            return input;
        };

        template <class Coords>
        ostream
    &operator<<(ostream &output, Triangle<Coords> &tr)
        {
            output<<"Triangle("<<tr.Coordinates1<<
                            ","<<tr.Coordinates2<<
                            ","<<tr.Coordinates3<<")";
            return output;
        };
```

I get strange errors, that should not occure:

```
stud\1mTRPO\labs\1\Lab2\iteration2.cpp|17|error: 'istream' does not name a type|
stud\1mTRPO\labs\1\Lab2\iteration2.cpp|30|error: 'ostream' does not name a type|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 4 seconds) ===|
```

I still can normally add it to iteration1.cpp, but I need it in iteration2.cpp.

I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 on Windows XP, compiling with

```
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions  -g
```

Is it time to change IDE?

How can I solve the problem? Thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Comment: The problem is most likely in one of the `//Content skipped here!!` sections.

Comment: @Anon Imous: Let me translate what I hear you are saying: "Guys, you please find out my problem! I can't be bothered to attempt tracking it down!" I had a look at your example code and I think the issue is with something you didn't post. Now I can spend time trying to recreate a similar problem, speculating what is in the invisible code, probably coming up with something which is different from the actual problem. Alternatively, you'd post the actual problem [although I fully expect that some silly error will emerge while creating an SSCCE which you'll spot yourself].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in incorrect addition of file.

The correct way is:

1) right click {projectname}-->Add files. Adding new file {filename}.

2) right click {filename} --> Properties... --> Build --> Uncheck all boxes in "Belongs in targets" field.

3) ????

4) PROFIT!!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the compiler compiles `iteration2.cpp` as a stand-alone translation unit! I'd recomment to:

1. Create a header file declaring the entities which need to be visible from `iteration2.cpp` (likewise probably for `iteration1.cpp`) and make sure the geader works without depending on other headers preceding it.
2. Change the `#include` directive to use the header.
3. Turn `iteration2.cpp` into a proper translation unit, i.e., including its own header as well as everything it depends on.

Comment: @Anon Imous: Based on what you commented abe, the problem is that you compiled the file as its own translation unit. There are certainly different ways to address this provlem, e.g., removing it being a separate translation unit from the project. I'd still follow what I recommended above!